# Whick is the Right Way to display a progress bar and stop user from touching other control in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

As a android base developer, i have always been using progressdialog for android. So is there any similar whay that i can popup a windows and showing a loading indicator which prevent users from touching any of the other control?  Currently i am looking at   ProgressIndicator  which allows me to make an indicator, however this does not prevent me from using other control while loading?

I also thought of making a childwindow with a loading dialog so this will prevent user from touching other control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider disabling the controls or making them invisible, then enabling them and/or making them visible when the process is complete. 
You can also have a TextBlock with a message while the process is happening and then make it invisible when complete..

Comment: i know disabling does work, however won't it abit weird :O? What are the current way that people do for windows phone 7 development?